# add Rolemanager to config file causes HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, config

I create a **Role** for my application and i added this role to the web.config as you can see :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="authentication" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa; password=1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="EducationDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EducationModel.csdl|res://*/EducationModel.ssdl|res://*/EducationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa; password=1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <!--<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="authentication" />
      </providers>
    </membership>-->

    <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="EducationMVC.Infrastructure.MyRoleProvider"  />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

As you can see this part of code is my role:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="EducationMVC.Infrastructure.MyRoleProvider"  />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

So After running i get this error :

> Config section 'system.web/roleManager' already defined. Sections must
>   only appear once per config file. See the help topic  for
>   exceptions  HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested
>   page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the
>   page is invalid

And this part of web.config is highlight :

```
   47:     <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false">
```

What is causing this?

Here is my role that i defined :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using EducationModel;

namespace EducationMVC.Infrastructure
{

    public class MyRoleProvider:RoleProvider
    {
       private readonly EducationDBEntities _dbcontext = new EducationDBEntities();

        public override void AddUsersToRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string ApplicationName
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public override void CreateRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool DeleteRole(string roleName, bool throwOnPopulatedRole)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] FindUsersInRole(string roleName, string usernameToMatch)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override string[] GetAllRoles()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
        {

            var objUser = _dbcontext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AppUserName == username);
            if (objUser == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                string[] ret = objUser.Roles.Select(x => x.RoleName).ToArray();
                return ret;
            }

        }


        public override string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void RemoveUsersFromRoles(string[] usernames, string[] roleNames)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool RoleExists(string roleName)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What question are you asking?

Comment: I asked i got the error !!!HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

Comment: @JohnSaunders i edit  my question error part,it says i define rolemanager twice

Comment: Have you checked the machine.config? You've probably got a roleManager defined in there.

Comment: No i didn't check .!!how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

But as the error is a self explanatory one, Remove this line

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

Comment: I removed i got this error :: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.

Answer (score 1):

I just add these lines to my web.config

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Different Situations :**
>
> - *This error usually occurs when using IIS 7/7.5 because the wildcard symbol (.*) is not used in later versions of IIS.*
>     **Fix this issue by removing the MIME type entry ".*", or replacing it with "**
> - *we dint give permissions of virtual directory to default user so for that we got error.* **We make it permissions to default user and
>     we should set application pool identity to default user then its
>     working fine now.**
> - *This problem occurs because the Application Host.config file or the Web.config file contains a malformed XML element.* **Delete the
>     malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config file or from the
>     Web.config file.**
>     if session time state creating problem then add this code in web.config file

---

> **If IIS configuration error occure... How to resolve this issue**
>
> - On Run type inetmgr to open IIS.
> - Select your website from the Sites panel.
> - For that site, click Edit Permission link from right Action panel.
> - Now a new property window will be opened.
> - Select Security Tab from the Property Window.
> - Select the user from Group or user names.
> - Now click the Edit button for the selected User.
> - If any of the listed deny checkboxes are checked then remove them.
> - as per your required permission level.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGINn.png)

```
<system.web>
     <authentication mode="Forms">
           <forms loginUrl="~/Page.aspx" timeout="2000"/>
     </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Your answer will be much more useful if you explain how this code snippet resolves the original problem.